# Why does USB Mountr cause two drives to appear?

Tags: usb, usb-mass-storage

When I mount an image in USB Mountr on Android 6 and use an OTG cable to connect the device to a Windows PC, two devices appear and two drives appear in File Explorer with the first one non-functional and the second being the image. Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?